# Invalid AAB ZIP file type While Uploading to Google Play

Tags: android, apk, android-app-bundle, apk-expansion-files

When I try to import a Bundle application (.AAB), Android tells me that the ZIP file is invalid. We followed the same steps presented in the documentation but nothing works.

What do I need to do?

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z81DL.png)

I have this message: `You have imported an invalid ZIP archive file.`

I generated it the same way as the following YouTube video: https://youtube.com/watch?v=d9sIbnVR5JQ. I did not touch the file after generation.

First, I designed a functional APK on any type of Android that I tested and validated. Then I transposed it into an AAB version in the same way as presented in the Play Store documentation and video.

Comment: Anything new on that?

Comment: We found the problem, it is with the private key for Play Store