# Getting "You've been importing an invalid ZIP file" when trying to upload my android (flutter) bundle to play store console

Tags: flutter, google-play, bundle

I don't know what to do to get rid of this error.

I build (successfuly) my bundle like so:

```
$ flutter build appbundle

 Building with sound null safety 

Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                             17,6s
✓ Built build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab
(61.1MB).
```

But when I try to add the aab file to the plays tore console page, I sometime get the following error (The translation from French stands for "You've been importing an invalid ZIP file"):

```
error
app-release.aab


Vous avez importé un fichier ZIP archive non valide.
```

I trie to `$flutter clear Android`but this makes no difference. I also tried to up the build number and generate a new bundle, but this makes no difference I still stick with the error.

I finally have to mention that I usually don't have any error.

Where does it come? What should I do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71342720/invalid-aab-zip-file-type-while-uploading-to-google-play private key perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out why I'm getting this error every now and then.
I never turn off my MacBook nor I close vscode or my projects. And What I think the reason is, is that with time going on, vscode or whatever flutter tools, comes unable to perform a normal build despite the appearance.

Anyway, to fix it:

- just close `vscode`;
- do a `flutter clean`;
- and finally `flutter build appbundle`.

Your bundle will be processed by Play store without any issue.

Hope it helps!